# Data Table SQL Server to variable C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I have a problem because I can't enter data from the table into the variable  error in English:

> Column 'id' does not belong to the table

Code

```
cmd.Connection = con;

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

RelacjaINT = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["id"]);
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. A good rule of thumb for asking questions, is that a professional helping you out would be pretty reasonable in putting in more than about 10% of the amount of effort that you put in in asking your question.. So if your question can be answered in 2.7 words, let it stand.. otherwise, you might want to add a bit more detail! :)

Comment: That error means the query *didn't* return a column named `id`. What does the query look like? What were the results? Debug your code and check the contents of `dt` after the call to `.Fill()`, especially the `Columns` collection

Comment: BTW you don't check whether there were any results. If the query returned no results `dt.Rows[0]` would throw

Answer (score -2):

Your DataTables not contain column.

```
cmd.Connection = con;

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("login", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("password", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("mail", typeof(string));
da.Fill(dt);
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    RelacjaINT = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id"]);
}
```

Comment: They don't have to. `Fill` will add whatever columns are returned by the data adapter

Comment: PS not my downvote but this is covered in docs and tutorials. Using `Convert.ToInt32(dr["id"])` isn't used either - if `ID` is a numeric column its contents are integers or decimals already. Otherwise, they need parsing. Check [DataAdapters and DataReaders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataadapters-and-datareaders) and [Populating a DataSet from a DataAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/populating-a-dataset-from-a-dataadapter) in the docs

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos.  Wrong. Fill() Only fills data in DataTable it does not create a columns. 
This example SqlDataAapter not contain columns
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

Comment: How are you going to access the values if the table doesn't have columns? That's not something new either, that's how ADO.NET worked since 2002. That's what's shown in the documentation, in the links I posted in the comment. There are two ways to load data - one using typed datasets and tables (in which case you specify all columns in advance)  and another is to load a DataTable from a DbDataReader either directly or through an adapter. In this case the columns are generated from the results.

Answer (score -2):

Check the datatype of the "id" column in the database and then convert it into appropriate int,double

Comment: This isn't a type cast error. It says, very specifically, that the column `id` doesn't exist

Comment: why double column type is int